# BASH tput error on stderr redirection

Tags: bash, redirect, token, stderr, tput

Writing a function that should display errors on terminal and save them to stderr

```
die () {
echo "$(tput setaf 1) ERROR: $*. Aborting...  $(tput sgr 0)" > &2 
exit 1 
}
```

unfortunately this will generate

```
syntax error near unexpected token `&'
`    echo "$(tput setaf 1) ERROR: $*. Aborting...  $(tput sgr 0)" > &2 '
```

I understood it was because of the tput but I am not able to figure out why.

I do not really care to have colors in my stderr but I would like to keep them on the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection to *stderr* is done by `>&2` - with no whitespace.

Comment: Yes, shame on me... I am always doing this kind of errors with shell scripting.